# "Spring" vs FFT spacial to frequency domain?

Tags: algorithms

Before I found out about FFT https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY but having seen and been impressed by spectrograms/sonograms, I developed my own algorithm for converting to the frequency domain from the spacial domain.

The following sudocode describes the approach.

```
// epsilon_n constants are small adjustable values

float[] wave = load_waveform() // input waveform
spring[] springs = new … // 1D springs representing frequencies
spectrogram = new float[wave.length,
    springs.length] // output frequencies over time

for (sample = 1 to wave.length)
    for (spring = 0 to springs.length) {
        phys_tick(
            springs[spring],
            abs(wave[sample - 1] - wave[sample])

        // output spring energy over time
        // swap out for any other approach
        spectrogram[sample, spring] = max(
            spectrogram[sample - 1, spring] * (1 - epsilon_4),
            abs(springs[spring].pos)
        )
    }

return spectrogram; // final output

// swap out for any other 1D spring model
// Updates a given springs values in two ways.
// Influences the spring with the waveform.
// Simulates the springs movement for the samples duration.
phys_tick(spring, sample_vel) {
    // push
    spring.pos += sample_vel × epsilon_1

    // phys
    if (spring.pos < 0) spring.vel += epsilon_2
    else spring.vel -= epsilon_2
    spring.pos += spring.vel

    // dampen
    spring.vel ×= 1 - epsilon_3
}
```

Q: How does the accuracy of this compare to other common approaches such as FFT?

Comment: Why not address this empirically? That is, write an analyzer using each algorithm and feed it synthetic inputs where you know what the correct results are.

Comment: I've not coded with FFTs and waveforms before, and I'm sure as well as the difficulty that some theory as to how well this should work would be helpful. It didn't seem to work too badly but it might just fundamentally not be a good way of solving this problem. Either way I hope it can be of some interest and insight and I hope that I've explained it well.